# Does anyone use Craft CMS to set up an intranet for client?

Tags: plugins, craft-features

I heard that Wordpress has a BuddyPress plugin could set up as intranet which has shared files, shared calendars, chat .. etc feature. Does Craft CMS has any plugin to do a similar feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There currently isn't a single plugin that does everything that BuddyPress does.

There are [calender](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/?q=calendar&) plugins, [commenting](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/?q=comment&) plugins, [social login](https://dukt.net/craft/social) and [oauth](https://dukt.net/craft/oauth) plugins and Craft Pro has built-in front-end registrations with member accounts with user groups and permissions. It would be up to you to tie all of these pieces together for your site's requirements.